# Problem with replacing a word in a file, using Python

Tags: python, file, replace

I have a .txt file containing data like this:

```
1,Rent1,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000  
1,Car Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000  
1,Flat Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000  
0,Rent2,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000  
0,Car Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000  
0,Flat Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000
```

I want to replace the first item. If it is 1, means it should remain the same but if it is 0 means I want to change it to 1. So I have tried using the following code:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("sample.txt",inplace=1):
    s=line.split(",")
    print a
    print ','.join(s)
```

But after successfully executed the program my .txt file looks like:

```
1,Rent1,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000

1,Car Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000

1,Flat Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000

0,Rent2,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000

0,Car Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000

0,Flat Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000
```

Now I want to remove the empty line. Is it possible, or is there any other way to replace the 0's?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250357/replace-a-word-in-a-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` adds an extra newline after the input and you already have one newline there. You should either strip the existing newline (`line.rstrip("\n")`) or use `sys.stdout.write()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
import fileinput
import re
p = re.compile(r'^0,')
for line in fileinput.FileInput("sample.txt",inplace=1):
    print p.sub('1,', line.strip())
```

The existing code you have doesn't actually change the lines like you want; `print a` doesn't do anything if `a` isn't actually defined! So you end up just printing a blank line (the `print a` bit) and then printing the existing line, hence why you get a file that's unaltered except for the addition of some blank lines.

Comment: +1: just replace `print re.sub(r'^0,', '1,', line)` with `print re.sub(r'^0,', '1,', line.strip())`, which will get rid of empty lines.

Comment: No need for the strip in the first place; just run it on the original file instead of the blank-lined one.

Comment: with Python26 on Win32 if you do not strip() or rstrip(), you get blank lines on the original file

Answer (score 1):

Either use `rstrip` to remove the trailing new lines before printing or use `sys.stdout.write` instead of `print`.

Also, if you only need to modify the first element, there is no need to split the entire line and join it again. You only need to split on the first comma:

```
line.split(',', 1)
```

If you want even better performance you could also just test the value of `line[0]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
fixed = []
for l in file('sample.txt'):
    parts = l.split(',',1)
    if(parts[0] == '0'):
        # not sure what you want to do here, but you want to "change this" number to 1?
        parts[0] = 1
    fixed.append(parts.join(','))
outp = file('sample.txt','w')
for f in fixed:
    outp.write(f)
outp.close()
```

This is untested, but it should get you most of the way there.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("sample.txt",inplace=1):
    s=line.rstrip().split(",")
    print a
    print ','.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a comma at the end of your [print](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/python_101/python_101.html#SECTION004310000000000000000) so that it doesn't add a newline. Like so:

```
print "Hello",
```

This is what I came up with:

```
input = open('file.txt', 'r')
output = open('output.txt', 'w')
for line in input:
    values = line.split(',')
    if (values[0] == '0'):
        values[0] = '1'
    output.write(','.join(values))
```

If you want a better csv handling library you might want to use [this](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) instead of split.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do it is to use the CSV parser :

```
import fileinput
import csv 

f = fileinput.FileInput("test.txt",inplace=1)
fichiercsv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

for line in fichiercsv:
    line[0] = "1"
    print ",".join(line)
```